# How to Write float data into Text file in Android Working with Unity and C#

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

im trying to Write the data Stored in a float variable into a text file.
it works well in PC using Streamwriter

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter();

but not on Android.

please tell me what is the way to Write it into a text file .
all i need is a similar way to write the above which works on android as well.
*collecting data from leap motion 
*each frame data has to be written into Text file.

Comment: Did my answer below help you with your problem?

Comment: yea thanks. @andeart

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of good resources in the Unity documentation/forums for this. Look up 'Unity File I/O' and you will find links to articles that are helpful.

Here's some sample code to help you with your specific problem:

```
public void WriteToFile()
{
    string FILE_PATH = Application.persistentDataPath + "/MYFILENAME.txt";
    if (File.Exists(FILE_PATH))
    {
        Debug.Log(FILE_PATH + " already exists.");
        return;
    }
    StreamWriter sr = System.IO.File.CreateText(FILE_PATH);
    sr.WriteLine ("This is line 1 to be written in file.");
    sr.WriteLine ("This is line 2.");
    sr.Close();
}
```

I hope that helps!